# Why does the JQuery valid() method always return True?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<form id="frmNewCategory">
    <span>New Category Name:</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNewCategoryName">
    <label>Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNewCategoryAmount">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="importantButton button" id="btnNewCategory">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="button" id="btnCancelNewCategory">
</form>
```

And a bit of jQuery-driven JavaScript using the [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) that fires when btnNewCategory is clicked:

```
function onNewCategoryClick(event)
{

    $("#frmNewCategory").validate(
        {
            rules:
            {
                txtNewCategoryName : { required: true },
                txtNewCategoryAmount : { required: true, number: true }
            },
            messages:
            {
                txtNewCategoryName : { required: "*" },
                txtNewCategoryAmount: { required: "*", number: "Invalid Amount." }
            }
        });


    if (!$("#frmNewCategory").valid())
        return;

    event.preventDefault();
    var cmd = cmdFactory.createUndoableNewCategoryCommand($(this));
    cmdBus.handleCommand(cmd);  
}
```

The method above is supposed to validate frmNewCategory. Trouble is that even if the form has invalid values or no values at all the .valid() method still returns True.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rules take form input "names" not "ids":

```
      <input type="text" name="txtNewCategoryName" />
      <input type="text" name="txtNewCategoryAmount" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a tricky problem to detect, because although the valid() method would return true, calling the .validate().element( "#selector" ) method would return false.

Comment: I've wasted 6 hours of this myself after going over two tutorials. I will dedicate my time to writing my own tutorial to highlight this significant issue in big words.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="txtNewCategoryName">
<input type="text" id="txtNewCategoryAmount">
```

Use:

```
<input type="text" name="txtNewCategoryName">
<input type="text" name="txtNewCategoryAmount">
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern worked for me before:

```
$(".required").filter(function () { return $(this).val() == ""; }).addClass("invalidInput");

if (this.formWrp.valid() && this.formWrp.find(".invalidInput").length == 0) 
     return true;
```

After doing so, it seems that validation is activated.